# How to state a person knows themselves in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the following predicates so far:

```
person(james).
person(jack).
knows(james,jack).
knows(jack,james).
```

My question is how do I use variables/constants say that someone knows themselves without explicitly going though all the persons and making them. I've tried:

```
knows(X,X).
```

but this just returns true.

Comment: `knows(X, X) :- person(X).`?

Comment: Would be nice if you put it in the answers so I could mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
knows(X, X) :- person(X).
```

The advantage over `knows(X, X).` is that not just anything passes:

```
?- knows(42, 42).
true.               % but it should be false
```